# IntelliJ throwing "java: error: option -source cannot be used together with --release"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

IntelliJ is throwing "*java: error: option -source cannot be used together with --release*" when trying to run ScalaTests.

***Note**: Using the bundled JRE and IntelliJ Idea 2021.2.2.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the --release compiler option in **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler**.